# CSS nested elements ignored by Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: css

This might be painfully easy, so my apologies in advance, but I'm on Hour 5 trying to figure this mess out.  Here's the UL I'm trying to present as a horizontal bar:

```
<div id="navbarwrapper">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="works.html">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="works.html">Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="works.html">Neighborhoods</a></li>
    <li><a href="works.html">Relocation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the strange CSS that seems to malfunction:

```
#navbar {}
#navbar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#navbar li {display: inline;}
#navbar ul li a {text-decoration:line-through;}
```

The problem I'm having is that with this markup, the text wrapped in anchor tags in the HTML aren't receiving line-through (I'm using line-through as a placeholder because it's obvious when it's working or not; I don't actually want a line-through in the end).

Here's the strange bit.  If I replace the "#navbar ul li a" nest with the following, it works:

```
#navbar li a {text-decoration:line-through;}
```

Furthermore, if I change "#navbar li{display: inline;}" with the following, I lose the inline property:

```
#navbar ul li{display:inline;}
```

Is it because I'm duplicating with "#navbar" and "ul"?  It seems entirely too strange to me, and I feel as though I've been able to use this syntax in the past without error.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are not correct.

`#navbar` is the UL element itself, so the selector `#navbar ul` does not target anything.

The correct selectors are

```css
#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbar li { display: inline; }
#navbar li a { text-decoration:line-through; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ul` already have id of `navbar`. That's why `#navbar ul` doesn't match anything.

`ul#navbar` will match.

Answer (score 1):

```
#navbar ul is wrong...#navbar is the ul itself.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<ul>` has the ID `#navbar`, so with `#navbar ul` you are actually addressing an additional `ul` inside your `ul`.

Try

```
ul#navbar li a {text-decoration:line-through;}
```